# Как сделать из куба параллелипипед C++ [OpenGL]?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

как сделать размеру куба тоесть X,Y,Z(Ширина, Высота, Глубина)?

Вот вершины куба:

```
    -size, -size, -size, size, -size, -size, size, size, -size,     // Face 1
    -size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size, size, size, -size,     // Face 1

    size, -size, size, size, -size, -size, size, size, -size,       // Face 2
    size, -size, size, size, size, size, size, size, -size,         // Face 2

    -size, -size, size, size, -size, size, size, -size, -size,      // Face 3
    -size, -size, size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size, -size,    // Face 3

    -size, -size, size, size, -size, size, size, size, size,        // Face 4
    -size, -size, size, -size, size, size, size, size, size,        // Face 4

    -size, -size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size, size, size,     // Face 5
    -size, -size, -size, -size, size, -size, -size, size, size,     // Face 5

    -size, size, size, size, size, size, size, size, -size,         // Face 6
    -size, size, size, -size, size, -size, size, size, -size        // Face 6
```

Comment: Поменяйте все size на соответствующие sizeX/sizeY/sizeZ. Либо используйте матрицу трансформации =) В любом случае, Вам стоит научиться рисовать не по точкам, а по вершинам - определяете 8 вершин куба, а треугольники рисуете по их индексам.

Comment: У меня рисуются GL_TRIANGLES (Вершинами). А как их правильно менять на X, Y, Z если может не правильно получится?

Comment: Подряд меняйте - каждая строка - один треугольник, три точки, 9 координат. Попробуйте xyzxyzxyz в каждом треугольнике. Теоретически порядок координат может быть другой, но это вопрос интерпретации, направлений мировой матрицы и т.п.

Comment: vp_arth, огромное спасибо вам я написал ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем я подставил X, Y, Z. Спасибо за помощь vp_arth

Получился код такой:

```
-cX, -cY, -cZ, cX, -cY, -cZ, cX, cY, -cZ,     // Face 1
-cX, -cY, -cZ, -cX, cY, -cZ, cX, cY, -cZ,     // Face 1

cX, -cY, cZ, cX, -cY, -cZ, cX, cY, -cZ,       // Face 2
cX, -cY, cZ, cX, cY, cZ, cX, cY, -cZ,         // Face 2

-cX, -cY, cZ, cX, -cY, cZ, cX, -cY, -cZ,      // Face 3
-cX, -cY, cZ, -cX, -cY, -cZ, cX, -cY, -cZ,    // Face 3

-cX, -cY, cZ, cX, -cY, cZ, cX, cY, cZ,        // Face 4
-cX, -cY, cZ, -cX, cY, cZ, cX, cY, cZ,        // Face 4

-cX, -cY, -cZ, -cX, -cY, cZ, -cX, cY, cZ,     // Face 5
-cX, -cY, -cZ, -cX, cY, -cZ, -cX, cY, cZ,     // Face 5

-cX, cY, cZ, cX, cY, cZ, cX, cY, -cZ,         // Face 6
-cX, cY, cZ, -cX, cY, -cZ, cX, cY, -cZ        // Face 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас единичный куб (ширина, высота, длинна равны 1.0). То можете поменять установить нужный вам масштаб:

```
glScalef(X, Y, Z);
```

Или применить соотвествующую матрицу трансформации.

Comment: Мне нужно именно размеры а не масштаб (Ширина X, Высота Y, Глубина Z)

Comment: А в чём разница в контексте вашей проблемы?